# Unable to create multiple tabs from array values in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Right now i am trying to create a multiple tab-host in android.
i.e., I am trying to show multiple tabs as per the size of the array which means if that array is having ten values i would like to show that 10 values in ten different tabs, but i am unable to parse those values.
Can anyone tell what mistake i am committing in my source?
suggestion please.

Thanks for your precious time!..

**LOGCAT**

```
    05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dynamic_tabhost/com.example.dynamic_tabhost.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:105)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at com.example.dynamic_tabhost.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 05-05 08:55:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(796):     ... 11 more
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

String[] arr_values = {"Tab1","Tab2","Tab3","Tab4","Tab5","Tab6","Tab7","Tab8","Tab9","Tab10"};
public static TabHost tabHost;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addTab(arr_values);
}

private void addTab(String[] values) 
{
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(values);
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView txtvw = (TextView)  tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.topics);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_values.length; i++) 
    {
        txtvw.setText(i);
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        }
    }   }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="1">


<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**tab_indicator.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topics"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tabview Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(values[i]);
```

This should be inside the for loop. Right now you update one tab in every loop.

You should create a new tab in every loop. Something like this:

```
tabHost = getTabHost();

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
{
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(values[i]);
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView txtvw = (TextView)  tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.topics);

    // Here you need to "cast" the Integer to String, otherwise Android will try to
    // find the String in the Resources.
    txtvw.setText(""+i);
    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

**Update:**

```
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
```

should be changed to this:

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

Comment: but eventhough this iline TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(values); is not accepting the array value which i've given why?

Comment: Because you have to call it with a String, not a String array. I have corrected it in the answer.

Comment: i got some error on my logcat, can you please tell me what it is saying.visit my question again for logcat details

Comment: Fixed it in my answer:)

Comment: i think in logcat "android.R.id.tabhost" is unavailable like that it is saying but i've mentioned it in my xml layouts, but i dont know why is saying like this? do you have any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51998/discussion-between-manick-and-kupsef)

Comment: Can you please tell me, don't should i used "TabHost tabs=getTabHost();" ?

Comment: You should use it, and it uses "@android:id/tabhost", that is why you have to change that line.